# How to make Ransack search field act as datepicker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, ransack

What should I do to make my fields act as datepicker? How to add calendar icon to them? 
part of my view code:

```
 <div class="row">
          <%=  f.label 'Create At' %>
          <%= f.search_field :created_at_beginning_of_day_gteq, class: 'form-control input-sm', 'datepicker' => true %>
          <%= f.search_field :created_at_end_of_day_lt, class: 'form-control input-sm',  'datepicker' => true %>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to do something like this: [image]

Comment: Which font library you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this a bit late, but I think that the following code might help.
`<%= f.date_field :business_date_gteq, class: 'form-control input-sm', 'datepicker' => true %>`

i.e. use date_field instead of search_field.

You could add an icon as suggested by @Charan

Answer (score 1):

I updated my answer.

Suppose If you are using [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/)

```
<div class="row">
    # You can change your label like this
    <%=  f.label 'Create At' %>
    <%= f.search_field :created_at_beginning_of_day_gteq, class: 'form-control input-sm', 'datepicker' => true %>
    <span class="fa fa fa-calendar calender-span"></span>

    <%= f.search_field :created_at_end_of_day_lt, class: 'form-control input-sm',  'datepicker' => true %>
    <span class="fa fa fa-calendar calender-span"></span>
</div>
```

Add this Style:

```
<style>
   .calender-span {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: red;
   }

</style>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks, but could you please see my update. I wasn't clear before, sorry

Comment: fontawesome. but it's not main question